# Does Go's sqlc supports join?

Tags: go, sqlc

I was reading the documentation for SQLC from https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/latest/howto/query_count.html. I wanted to use this in my project. However, I'm not seeing any documentation related to joining operations on the tables. Is it really possible in SQLC. If yes where I could find the documentation or reference?

Comment: There is now a documentation. See [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66220811/6309) below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A commit like "[cdf7025: Add MySQL json test](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/commit/cdf70253cf21c04712bad4158749c25ab939552d)" (or "[456fcb1 Add MySQL test for `SELECT * JOIN`](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/commit/456fcb1487f729d2f8e44256ad7e1817c32c5361)") suggests joins are supported.

2021: But it is true, as mentioned in [issue 643](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/issues/643), that queries with JOINs are for now *not* documented yet.

2023: the same [issue 643](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/issues/643#issuecomment-1731733936) now (Sept. 2023) includes a reference to the new documentation (thanks to [Kyle Gray](https://github.com/kyleconroy)):

> ### [Embedding structs](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/stable/howto/embedding.html)
>
> Embedding allows you to reuse existing model structs in more queries, resulting
> in less manual serialization work. First, imagine we have the following schema
> with students and test scores.
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TABLE students (
>   id   bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
>   name text NOT NULL,
>   age  integer NOT NULL
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE test_scores (
>   student_id bigint NOT NULL,
>   score      integer NOT NULL,
>   grade      text NOT NULL
> );
> ```
>
> We want to select the student record and the scores they got on a test.
> Here's how we'd usually do that:
>
> ```sql
> -- name: ScoreAndTests :many
> SELECT students.*, test_scores.*
> FROM students
> JOIN test_scores ON test_scores.student_id = students.id
> WHERE students.id = ?;
> ```
>
> When using Go, sqlc will produce a struct like this:
>
> ```golang
> type ScoreAndTestsRow struct {
>   ID        int64
>   Name      string
>   Age       int32
>   StudentID int64
>   Score     int32
>   Grade     string
> }
> ```
>
> With embedding, the struct will contain a model for both tables instead of a
> flattened list of columns.
>
> ```sql
> -- name: ScoreAndTests :many
> SELECT sqlc.embed(students), sqlc.embed(test_scores)
> FROM students
> JOIN test_scores ON test_scores.student_id = students.id
> WHERE students.id = ?;
> ```
>
> ```
> type ScoreAndTestsRow struct {
>   Student   Student
>   TestScore TestScore
> }
> ```

---

And [discussion 363](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/discussions/363#discussioncomment-6703684) points to the [changelog for `sqlc.embed`](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/stable/reference/changelog.html#sqlc-embed).

Comment: It's nearly 2 years and still no progress how to use joins

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan I agree. I monitor [discussion 363](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/discussions/363), as you do.

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan Finally :) There is now a documentation. See [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66220811/6309)